# ASP FormView and DetailsView return to default after postback

Tags: asp.net, postback, detailsview, formview

On my aspx file I have a couple labels, a FormView and a DetailsView.
During PreRender I manually set the Text of the labels (my application supports multiple languages, labels are set according to userprofile). Also the Text of labels inside the FormView and the DetaisView are set during PreRender. I use the .FindControl method to get references to the actual controls.
Finally, also during PreRender, I create various validator controls and manually add them to the FormView and the DetailsView.

When my page first loads all the above works just fine.

When I cause a postback, either press a button inside the FormView or DetailsView or change selection of a dropdownbox, page PreRender is fired; text is being set and validators created and added.

Now it comes; after the postback, as soon as the page refreshes in the browser, the labels show their default Text (as set in the aspx file) and my validator controls are simply gone.

Does anybody have experienced this as well, what is causing this behavior? And more important, how can I solve this?

**EDIT - Added sample code to reproduce**

I just made a very clean sample project to reproduce this behavior.
Here is the aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:FormView ID="fvwCalculateHeartRateZones" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsHeartRateZones" DefaultMode="Insert">
            <InsertItemTemplate>

                <asp:Label ID="lblHFMax" runat="server" SkinID="LabelHeader4" Text="_Max"></asp:Label>

                <asp:TextBox ID="txtHFMax" runat="server" SkinID="TextBoxDefault" Text='<%# Bind("iHFMax") %>' Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:Button ID="btnHFZCalculate" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" SkinID="ButtonDefault" Text="_Calculate" ValidationGroup="HFZCalculate" Width="100" />

            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>


        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsHeartRateZones" runat="server" 
            TypeName="HeartRateZones"
            DataObjectTypeName="HeartRateZones"
            InsertMethod="InsertByCalculation" >
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblHFMax = (Label)fvwCalculateHeartRateZones.FindControl("lblHFMax");
        lblHFMax.Text = "MaxP";

        Button btnHFZCalculate = (Button)fvwCalculateHeartRateZones.FindControl("btnHFZCalculate");
        btnHFZCalculate.Text = "Calculate";

    }
}
```

And finally the class being used by the ObjectDataSource

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public class HeartRateZones
{
    public int iHFMax { get; set; }

    public HeartRateZones()
    {
        //
        // Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public static int InsertByCalculation(HeartRateZones oAEntry)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

All very basic and simple. When you run the page you will see the captions of the label and the button are set to "MaxP" and "Calculate."

Before you press the Calculate button make sure you insert a digit value (e.g. 0). Then press the calculate button. You will see the captions of the label and the button return to their default values "_Max" and "_Calculate"

Comment: You should only do the initial bind when your page is not postback